# Unknown La'az in Teshuvot Rashi

Tags: history, rashi, language, rishonim

In the Elfenbein (1943) edition of Teshuvot Rashi, in the teshuvot from Rashi to the rabbis of Auxerre ('סימן ג), Rashi writes "לשון דמות צלם" is "אאמיינדליי" in la'az. [Elfenbein writes](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1734&st=&pgnum=66) in his footnotes that this word appears to have not been translated by Darmester & Blondheim in their books on la'azei Rashi. Does anyone know if the Old-French word Rashi is using has been identified since Elfenbein published? Or if it has been translated in some other sefer?

Comment: BTW, welcome to MY, I hope to see you around! :-)

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible that there is a similar modern French word? For la'azei Rashi in general, is the Old French too far removed from modern French for the latter to be informative about Rashi's meaning?

Comment: @MiYavin Rashi's French is often quite far away from Modern French. Actually Old French scholars study him to discover new old words. I speak French but the word above doesn't ring any bell

Comment: see Elfenbein's mevo, p. xlv, where he identifies it with the words *a Modele* http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1734&st=&pgnum=46&hilite=

Comment: @wfb I'd suggest posting that as an answer.